# Is one top level domain more inherently secure than another?

Tags: domain

There's an interesting discussion going on at work right now.  Someone wants to move their app off a .com domain and put it on a .net domain.  They contend a .net domain can provide the level of security which the .com domain was not able to provide.

I've never heard of one TLD being inherently more secure than another.  Is that a thing?

Comment: Domains provide no security at all.

Comment: What security was the speaker thinking about?

Comment: Aside from the availability of DNSSEC, there is no security difference between TLD's. And as far as I know, both .com and .net provide DNSSEC. It seems more like either change for the sake of change, or change based on misunderstandings.

Comment: @MechMK1. Thanks.  I assumed as much but wanted to confirm before I shot my mouth off.

Comment: I would ask the speaker about concrete security benefits. They're the one's making the claim, thus also the one's to provide evidence.